# VSCODE looking for snippets for react

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Like i say i am looking for VSCode snippets to do somethings like this in react :

```
.menu (+ press tab) = <div className="menu"></div>
span.menu ( +press tab ) = <span className="menu"></span>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the code?

Comment: Something like if i write : h3.title and i press TAB VSCODE transform that to <h3 className="title"></h3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [emmet snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/html#_emmet-snippets). To enable these in javascript files, [set](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "html",
    "javascriptreact": "html"
}
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks you dude